# Google Apps Script: `Those rows are out of bounds.` error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this issue: I download a excell file, upload it (converting it to google spreadsheet format) and I have to adapt it to a structure with which I can use it with my scripts. 
To do that, I have to delete several rows and columns of the excell file (there are some pictures and extra lines in the excell header). So, I'm writing a script to automate this tasks. But when I run this script, to delete the first 22 rows:

```
function onOpen() {  
  var menuEntries = [{name: "Format this sheet", functionName: "format"}];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  ss.addMenu("My scripts", menuEntries);

}

function format() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.deleteRows(0, 22);
//  sheet.deleteColumns(columnPosition, howMany)
}
```

I get this error:

`Those rows are out of bounds.` (the spreadsheet has more than 400 rows)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find my mistake: row counting starts with 1 and not 0, so I should be written: `sheet.deleteRows(1, 22);`